# Android, dynamically changing the view, adding/removing new components

Tags: java, android

I am an android newbie so forgive me if this question is simple.

Basically I want to port over a java project to Android. By view components in my java application dynamically change depending on the model. I.e the model being display may require n check boxes or n radio boxes depending on the enum TYPE being passed to the view.

In my java display this is achieved by nested loops with the n number each time adding the component to the screen. e.g a simplified version of the code:

```
if (type == TYPE.CHECKBOXES){
for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++){
add(new JCheckBox()); 
}}
```

This is processed for the view each time a next button is pressed (the type changes each time). In android how do i dynamically add and remove components, or do i need to set up a new view for each type?

Many thanks
Sam

Comment: What you do would work on android as well, just remember to use the correct android components. Just one edit: you would of course add your checkbox to your main view main layout (linearlayout etc.)

Comment: Agreed: Android and Swing are very similar in their event listening frameworks and layout setup. Minimal changes as suggested by Warzpit would just work fine on Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java you manage your layouts using `JPanel` alongwith specific layouts (i.e `BorderLayout`, `FlowLayout` etc.)
you add your components to `JPanel` and then add your `JPanel` to parent or root layout.

a little example (as you posted:)

```
if (type == TYPE.CHECKBOXES){
     for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++){
          mayPanel.add(new JCheckBox()); 
     }
}
```

In android you manage your layouts using `ViewGroup` which has specific subclassed layout design (i.e `LinearLayout` much like as `FlowLayout`, `RelativeLayout` may be considered `BorderLayout`)

You can use these layouts just like a `JPanel`

```
if (type == TYPE.CHECKBOXES){
     LinearLayout myPanel = new LinearLayout(this);
     for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++){
          CheckBox chk=new CheckBox(this);  
          chk.setText("Hello");
          myPanel.addView(chk); 
     }
     myRootPanel.addView(myPanel);
}
```

Just an addition: The `Component` in Java are called `View` in Android. Most of the control (also called widgets like `Button`, `EditText`, `ImageButton`, `ImageView`) in Android are subclass of `View`.

Answer (score 2):

Much like you would in HTML/CSS, you can create View elements and add them to your layout at run-time.  Just do some googling for examples.   Here's a good blog example:  http://android-elements.blogspot.com/2011/05/adding-views-to-layout-dynamically.html